# How to convert NSArray into Swift Array in swift 3

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsarray

I have two array

```
var arr1 = [NSArray]()
var arr2 = [String]()
```

And I want to convert `NSArray` into String Array 
I am using

arr2 = arr1 as! [String]

But it giving me error  :-

```
'NSString' is not a subtype of 'NSArray'
```

Is there any other method to convert?

Comment: arr1 is `Array<NSArray>` (swift array of NSArray) , not `NSArray`

Comment: how can I convert can you please suggest?

Comment: You should read about swift syntax first...

Comment: `arr1` is an array of arrays, not an array of strings. As an example, if the first element of arr1 contains an NSArray of [1, 2] and the second element is ["abc", "def"]. What do you want the string representation of this to be?

Comment: Array(nsArray) converts NSArray to [Any]

Answer (score 19):

```
var arr1 = [NSArray]()
```

is a swift array of NSArray. You are using wrong syntax for `NSArray`

In order to convert `NSArray` to swift Array

Use the proper syntax:

```
var arr1 = NSArray(objects: "a","b","c")

var objCArray = NSMutableArray(array: arr1)

if let swiftArray = objCArray as NSArray as? [String] {

    // Use swiftArray here
    print(swiftArray)
}
```

It will print

```
["a", "b", "c"]
```

Another way

```
let swiftArray: [String] = objCArray.compactMap({ $0 as? String })
```

no forced casting required.

Comment: No need `NSMutableArray`, just `if let ar = arr1 as? [String] {` should be enough.